# Can a lazy loaded module use a root injected canActivate guard?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a [stackblitz books module](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-slice-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbooks%2Findex.ts) with the following paths:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'find', component: FindBookPageComponent },
  { path: ':id', component: ViewBookPageComponent },
  { path: '', component: CollectionPageComponent },
];
```

Within the same app there is also a root injected `AuthGuard` service sitting in the `services` folder.  If that guard is added to any of the routes in the books module, the application spins forever and will not launch.

Can a root injected `CanActivate` guard be used in a module without specifying it in the `providers` array of the module?

[The documentation I have looked at show the guards being registered with the `AppComponent` providers](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular-route-guards/), so I assumed that it would be ok to root inject the guards?

If it has to be specified, can it still be root injected?

The `AuthGuard` depends on a `StateService` and if it cannot be root injected, then neither can the `StateService` I assume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a root injected CanActivate guard be used in a module without specifying it in the providers array of the module?

Technically it already is specified. The `@Injectable({provideIn: 'root'})` tells the Angular compiler to add it to the main module's list of providers. It is just a convenience feature that was added to Angular.

The root module is the one defined by `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(module)` in your entry TypeScript file (it's usually named `main.ts`).

> If that guard is added to any of the routes in the books module, the application spins forever and will not launch.

Sounds like the `AuthGaurd` returns an observable that does not complete. Try adding a `return observable.pipe(first());` to the guard function.

All of the router features that use observables (canActive, canLoad, resolve, etc.) require that the observables complete.

> The documentation I have looked at show the guards being registered with the AppComponent providers, so I assumed that it would be ok to root inject the guards?

In this case, the module is the same as the one where the root routes are declared. You can see that `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)` is used to import the router with the top-level routes. So anything defined in the providers at this level will be seen by the router, because they both share the same injector.

> The AuthGuard depends on a StateService and if it cannot be root injected, then neither can the StateService I assume?

If a provider has not been declared when the injector tries to instantiate a class, then you get a run-time error that the constructor has an unknown injectable. It's a message that looks something like this `error: constructor(?)` where the question mark is the unknown parameter.

This means that if `StateService` is defined as a provider later, then `AuthGaurd` will just fail to be started. This depends upon when `AuthGaurd` is *first* used, because they are not created until they are first used.

Comment: all your comments are precisely in line with my understanding, and I changed the guard implementation so that it navigates to `login` and just returns `of(false)` ... that way it definitely returns ... but the app still just spins .... So maybe Stackblitz is broken.  I'll try breaking it down into really tiny pieces to find out what's going on.